# Git: Roll back to much earlier version

Tags: git

Is there a way to roll back to a much earlier version of what was checked into git (for the entire repo)? I don't want to change what is in the repo, I just want a local copy of where the repo was 9 months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just clone the repo...

```
git clone <repo-url>
```

...find the commit, branch or tag you want from 9 months ago...

```
git log
git branch
git tag
```

...and then checkout the older version...

```
git checkout <commit-sha1, branch, tag>
```

Keep in mind if you checkout a commit, you'll be in detached HEAD mode. You can create a branch to that commit if you wish to commit further.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. This git repo does not have branches. It's just a lot of commits... When I do: git checkout <commit-sha1> I receive an error "error: The following untracked working tree files would be removed by checkout:" Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: @Sparky1 You could `stash` your changes, commit them to a branch, or remove them.

Comment: It's a fresh clone. I've made no changes since I cloned. Do you mean that I need to stash all the commits that have happened in the 9 months after the commit that I want to roll back to?

Comment: @Sparky1 No. I'm not too familiar with the message you're seeing either.

Comment: It worked! I had to make another fresh clone and try it a second time, but it worked! Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Sparky1 No worries. Check out [rob's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14206346/31671) too as it's got a useful shortcut to jumping back 9 months.

Answer (score 2):

You can literally just tell git to checkout out a branch as of 9 months ago.  Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
:; git checkout 'master@{9 months ago}'
Checking out files: 100% (625/625), done.
Note: checking out 'master@{9 months ago}'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at b50869f... ignore DerivedData
```

All of the ways to specify a revision are documented in [the `git-rev-parse` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html).